# allign center video background in a smaller div/container

Tags: html, css, video, background

I'm trying to center a video background in a smaller div/container.
an example of what exactly I'm looking for is [here](http://landhostudio.com/)(the video with the bike).
the video is centered to the container so it cut some right and some left.
how I can do it??
thanks

I tried this code but don't work well.. as I tell up there, I need that video in contained and centered into the div, so it will be cut to left and right, exactly like the example I show you.

thanks to everyone who will help me!

```css
.video-backgroud {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 1;
  }
```

```html
      <div class="gridvideo" itemprop="video">
        <video class="video-background" preload="auto" loop="" autoplay="" muted="" poster="http://tommasoottomano.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/back-sito-ok-copia-1.png" data-vps-id="0ccff4a1-e9d1-d6a7-f2af-836828e2b1b3" data-vps-speed="1">
          <source src="http://tommasoottomano.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/HOV_chapter-one_The-rule-of-Nature-sito.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
      </div>
```

Comment: Check my answer is working well for you or not?

Answer (score 1):

Replace your css with this:

```
         .gridvideo{
              display:block;
              position: absolute; 
              padding: 15px 10px;
            } 
             .video-backgroud {
            display: block;
            position: relative;
            }
```

You can control the gap between your div and your video by changing the padding in **.gridvideo**

Comment: I don't think I've made myself clear, sir. i already have a full width raw with 2 column 50% / 50% they are square, i put full height so they cover all height, but the problem is that they are aligned to left, and i want that the video is centered, exactly how i show in the link in the post! this code don't help me :(

Answer (score 0):

Please try this below code.

I have just added `margin: 0px auto;` to `video.video-background` class. so using `margin:0px auto` it will set video in center of the screen.

```
video.video-background {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 1;
  margin: 0px auto; // added this property as new
  }
```

**If video container is still not center using above class then please added class.**

```
.gridvideo{display:block;} // Here you can set display:flex
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't think I've made myself clear, sir. i already have a full width raw with 2 column 50% / 50% they are square, i put full height so they cover all height, but the problem is that they are aligned to left, and i want that the video is centered, exactly how i show in the link in the post! this code don't help me :(